# Arduino Due uploading error using Eclipse plugin "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"

Tags: arduino-due, eclipse

I have a Arduino Due that I'm trying to upload a sketch to. I follow the tutorial http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Eclipse to get the board running with the Eclipse plugin.

However uploading the sketch gives me the error

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
```

If I use the Arduino IDE everthing works fine. I'm using Eclipse mars with Arduino 1.6.5

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

There's your clue. 
1) programmer is not responding - This usually means the device isn't connected, or powered, or reachable by the IDE, make sure you have eclipse configured correctly for your device, and it's location.

2) not in sync - This is a redundant, or overlapping error, of course it's not going to sync if it can't connect.

Comment: The weird thing is if I press erase and reset on the Due before uploading the sketch it runs without any problems! I thought the Due has auto reset functionality?

Comment: I searched for a solution to this problem but it seems to be that I'm not the only one who struggles with that: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=167492.0. They found some fix but these are a little bit ugly. I'm also worried about damaging my board if I press each time erase when uploading my sketch.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong upload tool.

The due is not using avr dude as upload tool.
You need to use bossac.

If you turn on verbose upload in the arduino ide preferences you will see

```
...arduino\tools\bossac\1.6.1-arduino/bossac.exe ...
```